# PHP not displaying time from database correctly

Tags: php

I have a script that count downs the time until an event start

[image]

Start date and start time is retrieved from a database.

**My Problem**

Days is calculated correctly but ***hours*** are the same for each event and does not get calculated correctly

```
while(){
$gameDate = $row['event_date'];
$time=$row['event_time'];

        $calcDate = $gameDate.$time;
        $calcDate =  strtotime(str_replace('/', '-', $gameDate)); 
        $remaining = $calcDate - time();
        $days_remaining = floor($remaining / 86400);
        $hours_remaining = floor(($remaining % 86400) / 3600); 
}
```

**EVENTS table**

[image]

Again notice in the 1st image how hours are displayed as 13 for both events even though it is different times for both events in the database

*Any idea what I am doing wrong here or how I can improve the script?*

Comment: are you using jquery countdown js?

Comment: @new_bee_magento no this is a php script as you can see in the code

Comment: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/5b6ffe97f3bbc23290266c2dbe2ef7afe1b4b1ec you were passing `$gameDate` in your strtime, you should be instead bassing `$calcDate`, else you will strtotime only the **date** and not the **datetime**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an error in this line:

```
$calcDate =  strtotime(str_replace('/', '-', $gameDate));
```

Replace `$gameDate` by `$calcDate` which contains your full date + time string you created one line before:

```
$calcDate =  strtotime(str_replace('/', '-', $calcDate));
```

Or just make it this way:

```
$data = array(
   array('event_date' => '2015-07-13', 'event_time' => '15:00'),
   array('event_date' => '2015-07-11', 'event_time' => '20:00')
);

foreach ($data as $row) {
   $calcDate =  strtotime(str_replace('/', '-', $row['event_date'].$row['event_time'])); 
   $remaining = $calcDate - time();
   $days_remaining = floor($remaining / 86400);
   $hours_remaining = floor(($remaining % 86400) / 3600); 
   echo $days_remaining." ".$hours_remaining."\n";
}
```

Working code: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/128a284a176098ede0dfc7bc18cfc5f7081d2afa

So you avoid to mix up the different variables. ;-)

Comment: Andre Thank you soo much, im gonna implement it and let you know the result

Comment: Andre you have no idea how grateful I am for your help, I wish I could do more than simply accept your answer, thank you sooo much it works great!